# Installing All Go Mod Dependency Binaries

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using go1.16.3 with this tools file to consolidate dependencies:

```
// +build tools

package main

import (
    _ "github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag"
    _ "honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck"
)
```

Running `go get` in the project dir downloads and installs the packages to `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` but doesn't install their binaries to `$GOPATH/bin`. Running `go get` individually for each mod (i.e. `go get github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag`) *does* install both packages and binaries.

Is there a way I can install the binaries for all mods with a single command?

If not, what's the right way to automatically install all packages and binaries for all dependencies?

Comment: `go.mod` specifies modules, which are not binaries, though some may correspond to `main` packages. The import path `github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag` is not a module, it is a `main` package (also note the deprecation notice when you run `go get` on that package). It would be very unusual to want every single `main` package from within every single module dependency to be installed. Normally you just have a command to install the specific binaries you want.

Comment: I think a shell script is the proper tool for this problem.

Comment: This article has a good rundown on how to conveniently script this process out: https://marcofranssen.nl/manage-go-tools-via-go-modules

Comment: @JimB Installing each of these individually means either keeping a build script in sync with the tools file manually or parsing the tools file. Is that really the right way to handle this? I thought the tools file was supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't want to keep the build script in sync with the tools file, then make the script install the packages based on the `tools.go` file import paths. I have never seen this become an actual problem, since these change very infrequently, and it's immediately apparent if you don't have a tool installed which is called later on in the build process.

Comment: @Adrian do you use that method? It seems hacky, but I can't find anything better.

Comment: @Dave not personally, no. If the build is complex, I have a makefile step that installs tools required for the build process, and manage that list in the makefile. But YMMV, and there is no one "right way" to manage these kinds of tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really a good way to do this in a single command. Your best bet might be a script that chains a `go list` command to list all the imports from tools.go into a `go install` command:

```sh
tools=$(go list -f '{{range .Imports}}{{.}} {{end}}' tools.go)
go install $tools
```

---

To explain the above, `go list` queries packages and modules. By default, it just prints package names, but its output can be controlled with `-f` or `-json`. [`go help list`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-List_packages_or_modules) shows everything `go list` can print. The syntax for `-f` is the same as [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template).

So here, `go list tools.go` queries a package which is a list of .go files, in this case, just tools.go. `.Imports` is a sorted, deduplicated list of imports from that package. We could just use the template `{{.Imports}}`, but it prints brackets at the beginning and end.

```
$ go list -f '{{.Imports}}' tools.go
[github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck]
```

So instead, we range over `.Imports`, and inside the range, we print each import (`{{.}}`) followed by a space.

Comment: It's a bummer that the tools file was settled on without fixing this, but this ^ approach is much better than parsing it.

Comment: @Dave I agree the tools.go idiomatic is kind of unsatisfying. I hope we'll come up with something better in the future that addresses private dependencies, too.

Comment: One other option is to decouple the tool versions from the `go.mod` file, and just make it a shell script that installs tools at known versions: `go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.7.1 && go install honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.2.0`

Comment: ```go install $(go list -f '{{range .Imports}}{{.}} {{end}}' tools.go)$(go list -f '{{range .Imports}}{{.}} {{end}}' tools.go)```